# Android - Alert Dialog always return the same value

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

the function I want to create is the app will show bus top icon on Google map and if the user click the icon it will show a info window, and then after the user click the info window it will show alert box to ask the user set the bus top as origin stop or destination stop, and then it will pass data to on top text box, BUT now the problem is no matter I press which bus stop it will give the same bus stop number which is the last one in the arraylist, I realize the reason is because I use for loop here, but I dont know how to modify, please help me, thanks!

```
public class Passing extends FragmentActivity {

private EditText Name;
private EditText Name2;
Button button1;
private GoogleMap googleMap;

public String stopLon;
public String stopLat;
public String stopName;
public String stopRoad;
public String stopCode;
public String OriginLoc;
public String DestinationLoc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_passing);
    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    String Bus = intent2.getExtras().getString("Bus");

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    db.open();
    String oriRoute = db.getRoute(Bus).toString();
    String route = oriRoute.substring(1, oriRoute.length() - 1);
    String[] bustop = route.split(" ");
    ArrayList<String> stopList = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList(bustop));

    Cursor stopLoc;
    for (int i = 0; i < stopList.size(); i++) {
        stopLoc = db.getStop(stopList.get(i));
        stopLon = stopLoc.getString(1);
        stopLat = stopLoc.getString(2);
        stopName = stopLoc.getString(3);
        stopRoad = stopLoc.getString(4);
        stopCode = stopLoc.getString(5);
        double lon = Double.parseDouble(stopLon);
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(stopLat);
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
        marker.position(new LatLng(lat, lon));
        marker.title(stopName);
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Passing.this);
                alert.setTitle("Trip Setting");
                alert.setMessage("Pls choose Start Location and Destination");
                alert.setPositiveButton("Origin Stop", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                        String originStopCode = stopCode;
                        Name.setText(originStopCode);
                        OriginLoc = stopLat + "," + stopLon;
                    }
                });

                alert.setNegativeButton("Destination Stop",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                        String destinationStopCode = stopCode;
                        Name2.setText(destinationStopCode);
                        DestinationLoc = stopLat + "," + stopLon;
                    }
                });

                // Setting Netural "Cancel" Button
                alert.setNeutralButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please choose the Origin & Destination Stops",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                // Showing Alert Message
                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }
    db.close();

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setEnabled(false);

    Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
    Name2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name2);

    Name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            String Name1 = Name.getText().toString();
            String Name11 = Name2.getText().toString();
            if (Name1.equals("") || Name11.equals("")) {
                button1.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                button1.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    Name2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            String Name1 = Name.getText().toString();
            String Name11 = Name2.getText().toString();

            if (Name1.equals("") || Name11.equals("")) {
                button1.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                button1.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.passing, menu);
    return true;
}

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {

    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    String Bus = intent2.getExtras().getString("Bus");

    Intent intent3 = getIntent();
    String TripName = intent3.getExtras().getString("TripName");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainPage.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name2);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    String message2 = editText2.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra("StartLo", OriginLoc);
    intent.putExtra("EndLo", DestinationLoc );
    intent.putExtra("Name", message);
    intent.putExtra("Name2", message2);
    intent.putExtra("BusNo", Bus);
    intent.putExtra("Trips", TripName);
    startActivity(intent);

}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiate the
    // map
    if (googleMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapView)).getMap();
        // googleMap = getSupportFragmentManager().
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map
        if (googleMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    // Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    // Get Current Location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    // Set Map type
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    // Get latitude and longitude of current location
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
    double longtude = myLocation.getLongitude();
    // Create a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longtude);
    // Show the current location in Google Map
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
    // Zoom in the Google Map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
 }

 }
```

Comment: I guess you should setOnClick for marker to show the alert.

Comment: is it always the last item's result ?

Comment: @Rudi how to setOnClick, is it same like the onClick? yes always the last stop item, i think because i use for loop and inside the code i write like this "String originStopCode = stopCode;" so after for loop end, it will only save the last item, but i dont know how to modify

Comment: I guess it's because googleMap is final.

Comment: where did you implemented googleMap ?

Comment: wait a while, i edit my question and put all the code, pls help me check

Comment: cool and i wrote an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok leave the `GoogleMap googletest` in the beginning and add this line before for loop :

```
GoogleMap googleTest = googleMap;
```

then use `googleTest` inside the for loop instead of `googleMap`

hope it helps mate

Comment: I try but got error, can i do something to modify the for loop?

Comment: well the problem is you are using googleMap in other part of the class as well. let me check

Comment: the problem was that when you implement a parameter in the beginning and put it in the for loop , it always get the latest value. Now we should find a way to implement it inside the loop

Comment: Ok I changed the answer, try it plz , hope it works :)

Comment: Ok is it leave the GoogleMap googleMap and define a new variable GoogleMap googleM = googleMap, right?

Comment: emm i dont know why, the app show this message "..has stopped unexpectedly"...is it possible that  i send my code to your email with a simple explanation, actually this is the last error for my project..

Comment: sure, send it for me :) but  i dont know how to pass my email here :D

Comment: wangqb1117@gmail.com this is my email, maybe u can just send me a email first~~Thanks!!!!